# Is there a way to run wcf3.5 rest api in an integrated app pool

Tags: asp.net, wcf

Is there possibly another way to run my WCF 3.5 Rest API in an IIS integrated app pool?

Here's the message in the event viewer:

> A request mapped to aspnet_isapi.dll was made within an application
>   pool running in Integrated .NET mode.  Aspnet_isapi.dll can only be
>   used when running in Classic .NET mode.  Please either specify
>   preCondition="ISAPImode" on the handler mapping to make it run only in
>   application pools running in Classic .NET mode, or move the
>   application to another application pool running in Classic .NET mode
>   in order to use this handler mapping.

And here's the handler entry in my web.config under `system.webServer > handlers`:

```
<add name="svc-ISAPI-2.0_64" path="*.svc" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to *change* the handler registration to one of these:

```
<add name="svc-Integrated" path="*.svc" verb="*"
 type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler, System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
 preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0" />

<add name="svc-Integrated-4.0" path="*.svc" verb="*"
 type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpHandlerFactory, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
 preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

Which ono to use depends on the .Net Framework version that is set on the `Application Pool`. Based on your existing handler registration, the first one should be correct.

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you please explain a little more what was happening in my case and how this resolved it? If not, no worries, I understand. And again, thank you!